# Migración en Laravel, error al crear la llave foranea

Tags: laravel, migration

Tengo un error al momento de realizar una migracion en Laravel, no me deja crear la llave foranea:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_cliente_id_foreign` foreign key (`cliente_id`) references `cliente` (`id`))

```
 public function up()
     {
        Schema::create('cliente', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('nombres',60);
            $table->string('apellidos',60);
            $table->string('rfc',13);
            $table->string('noidentificacionine',15);
            $table->string('email',40);
            $table->date('fechanacimiento');
            $table->unsignedInteger('numeroreferencia');
            $table->unsignedInteger('foliossiac');
            $table->unsignedInteger('telefonotelmex');
            $table->unsignedInteger('ordenasignada');
            $table->datetime('fechadecaptura');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
     }

 public function up()
     {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');

            $table->unsignedInteger('cliente_id');
            $table->foreign('cliente_id')->references('id')->on('cliente');

            $table->string('name', 60);
            $table->string('last_name', 60);
            $table->string('email', 45)->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();


        });

     }
```

Estos son mis migraciones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los tipos de datos deben ser los mismos, es decir mientras en tu tabla clientes tienes:

```
bigIncrements("id");
```

En tu tabla users tienes:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('cliente_id');
```

Modifica la última línea a esto:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('cliente_id');
```

Lo anterior debido a que desde la versión de Laravel 5.8 cuando creas una migración, el tipo de dato por defecto usado para las `PK` es `BIGINTEGER` representado como `unsignedBigInteger`.

[Referencia](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#indexes)

Comment: Muchas Gracias, si funcionó.