# Error en laravel al hacer php artisan migrate:fresh

Tags: laravel

Tengo un error al querer agregar una clave foránea desde una migración que estoy definiendo en mi código ya intente hacer rollback a mi anterior migración, tambien ya borré y volví a crear la base de datos(ando usando Laragon)

Anexo los Scheme con los que estoy definiendo como crear las tablas en la migración.

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->comment('nombre de rol de usuario');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedInteger('role_id')->default(\App\Role::STUDENT);
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('picture')->nullable();

        //cashier
        $table->string('stripe_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('card_brand')->nullable();
        $table->string('card_last_four')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('trial_ends_at')->nullable();

        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();


    }

    );
    Schema::create('subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('stripe_id');
        $table->string('stripe_plan');
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->timestamp('trial_ends_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('ends_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('user_social_accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('provider');
        $table->string('provider_uid');
    });
}
```

y la imagen del error que me bota en consola al poner el comando.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deja pongo todo el código de la migración en la publicación, gracias por responder

Comment: En la tabla `users`, tienes `$table->id();`, Que es un alias de `$table->bigIncrements('id')`, por lo tanto la llave foránea `user_id` en la tabla `subscriptions` debería ser `unsignedBigInteger`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, si se solucionó cambiando el tipo de dato ahora solo me falta checar un pequeño error de duplicidad en mi columna de stripe_id

Comment: Posible duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/269860/migraci%C3%B3n-en-laravel-error-al-crear-la-llave-foranea

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Migración en Laravel, error al crear la llave foranea](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/269860/migraci%c3%b3n-en-laravel-error-al-crear-la-llave-foranea)